# New Line without Space Afterwards

Tags: support, mathjax, markdown

Please forgive me if this question has been asked before, but I haven't been able to find it. On Mathematics SE, what code/command/operation starts a new line without space afterwards? Thank you very much!

The following in green is what I desire. I typed the second equation in a new line after the first.

$ \color{green}{\nabla \times A = 0} $
$ \color{green}{\nabla \times B = 0} $

However, I tried to achieve the same formatting for the following two equations in red. Why doesn't it work?

$ \color{red}{= \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{lmk}\partial_j \partial_lA_m} $
$ \color{red}{= (\delta_{il}\delta_{jm} - \delta_{im}\delta_{jl}) \partial_j \partial_lA_m }$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that your problem is the spacing after your first line.  For example,

$ \color{red}{= \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{lmk}\partial_j \partial_lA_m} $
$ \color{red}{= (\delta_{il}\delta_{jm} - \delta_{im}\delta_{jl}) \partial_j \partial_lA_m }$

will do it, where I took your $\TeX$ and added two spaces after your first line.

Comment: By the way, this is probably not the best place to ask this question, as this is really a $\TeX$ question more so than a MSE question.

Comment: Thank you JavaMan. So all that's necessary is to ensure that there are two spaces after each line?

Comment: @LaPrevoyance I'm not sure about what's necessary or best, but you can see that the only difference between your green equations and the red ones was only the spacing after the end of the first line.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I disagree with the first comment: this is a Markdown question, not a TeX question at all. The two equations could be any two blocks of text. The fact that two trailing spaces create a line break is a part of [Markdown syntax](http://warpedvisions.org/projects/markdown-cheat-sheet/).

Comment: So, is meta-m.se the best place to ask Markdown questions?

Comment: @GerryMyerson OK, so I disagreed only with the second part of the first comment. Quite possibly not the best place. Although for an issue that could, for all the OP knew, be caused by interaction of MathJax and Markdown, it's not a bad place either.

Answer (score 1):

Joining it into one formula and adding `\\` would also work. (But I think that the [markdown](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#linebreaks) solution is cleaner - i.e. using two spaces or adding `<br/>`.)

$ \color{red}{= \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{lmk}\partial_j \partial_lA_m} \\
 \color{red}{= (\delta_{il}\delta_{jm} - \delta_{im}\delta_{jl}) \partial_j \partial_lA_m }$

This was typeset as:
`$ \color{red}{= \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{lmk}\partial_j \partial_lA_m} \\
 \color{red}{= (\delta_{il}\delta_{jm} - \delta_{im}\delta_{jl}) \partial_j \partial_lA_m }$`

AFAIK this works in MathJax, but not in TeX.

It would work similarly in centered formula

$$ \color{red}{= \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{lmk}\partial_j \partial_lA_m} \\
 \color{red}{= (\delta_{il}\delta_{jm} - \delta_{im}\delta_{jl}) \partial_j \partial_lA_m }$$